# How context works inside php foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I'm writing a simple tab navigation and I'm facing this issue:

The function `print_office` works only when I'm inside a foreach.

```
//Doesn't work
print_office($loop->posts[0], true);

//Works
foreach ($loop->posts as $index => $post) {
    print_office($post, true);
}
```

The `print_office` function makes use of Advanced Custom Fields' `get_field('field_name')`.

EDIT:

I've put a `var_dump($office)` inside `print_office`.

When called **outside** the `foreach` I get:

```
object(WP_Post)#317 (24) {
  ["ID"]=> int(7)
  ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1"

  [.....] //More fields;
}
```

When called **inside** the `foreach`I get:

```
FOREACH:object(WP_Post)#317 (24) {
  ["ID"]=> int(7)
  ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1"

  [.....] //More fields;
}
```

So the only difference is that: `FOREACH:object` instead of just `object`.

Comment: php is pass-by-value by default. there should be NO operational difference between the two. basic debugging: `var_dump($loop->posts)` and see what your'e dealing with. maybe you DON'T have an index `0`.

Comment: Is `$loop->posts` and `Array` or `ArrayIterator` or what?

Comment: Please show the surrounding code. Wordpress relies on a bunch of global variables (mainly due to its age and backward compatability, but anyway..), so i can think of a few reasons for this, but more information is required.

Comment: `var_dump($office)` prints stuff like `FOREACH:object` is there any `runkit` stuff around?

Comment: A `foreach` construct never ever manipulates the flow within a function!! But `foreach` creates a copy of you array and takes that. So cunstructs like  `foreach(functionX() as $result){}` will work in PHP. But the function is only called once, not at every loop.

Comment: On the other side `while($result=functionX()){ }` will call the function in each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that, when it does not work, there's no $post variable, and the get_field('field_name') returns the field for the current post, which is really $post

Comment: That was it. 

I was overriding `$post` in the `foreach`, that's why it worked inside but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

That look like `$loop->posts` is an associative array (like a JS Object) or that `$loop->posts` extends the `Traversable` interface but not the `ArrayAccess` interface.

### Example Associative array

If your array looks like this:

```
<?php
     $loop->posts = array(
         'key1' => 'Post message 1',
         'key2' => 'Post message 2'
     );
?>
```

you can't access "Post message 1" via `$loop->posts[0]`. But you can via `$loop->posts['key1']`

### Travesable / ArrayAccess

There is a good explanation for [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) and [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) on [php.net](http://php.net)